# Autofill suggested emails from system/Google account with keyboard for email text field?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield, android-autofill-manager

I know we can save email and password (Android/Google password manager/ auto fill service) if signing in the app and keyboard can suggest saved accounts

But if a user installs the app for the first time, how can we suggest an email from the system/Google account without password and without typing nothing at all?

For now I need to start typing some email before keyboard suggests the email

**Update**

Found the following [example](https://bryanherbst.com/2021/04/13/compose-autofill/):

```
@Composable
fun AutofillEmail() {
  var email by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
  val autofillNode = AutofillNode(
    autofillTypes = listOf(AutofillType.EmailAddress),
    onFill = { email = it }
  )
  val autofill = LocalAutofill.current

  LocalAutofillTree.current += autofillNode

  OutlinedTextField(
    modifier = Modifier.onGloballyPositioned {
      autofillNode.boundingBox = it.boundsInWindow()
    }.onFocusChanged { focusState ->
      autofill?.run {
        if (focusState.isFocused) {
          requestAutofillForNode(autofillNode)
        } else {
          cancelAutofillForNode(autofillNode)
        }
      }
    },
    value = email,
    onValueChange = { email = it }
  )
}
```

but it only works for Google Autofill service:

[image]

[image]

On Samsung devices the default Autofill service is Samsung Pass

[image]

but nothing appears

Why Samsung doesn't suggest to autofill email of my Samsung account at least? My device is signed in to both Google and Samsung accounts...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need at least one email registered in Samsung Pass to enable the autofill, check the logs.

Comment: What do you mean? I have Samsung account

Comment: Google autofill service worked after three steps : Enable Autofill service in settings, User agree using Autofill service dialog after access Google user info in Settings, then last steps, save password in Password Manager

Comment: So for samsung, you also need these steps. Which steps did you not pass? ex. did you store any 3rd login info in your samsung password manager?

Comment: Your sample code totally works for me